# Почему в гугл поиск по картинке используется get метод

Tags: html

Почему в гугл поиск по картинке используется get метод я читал что для загрузки картинки используется post
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

не туда посмотрел, все нашёл теперь post
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]